# Evaluate expression with stringify operation in C

Tags: c, macros, preprocessor, stringify

I am trying to make something normally simple but not sure it's possible directly using C macro/preprocessing.
I have an expression with operation defined as something like

```
#define EXPR_TEST (4+2)
```

(actually `EXPR_TEST` expression is more complex than that but anyway...)

I would like the evaluated result to be stringified inside usage of `printf` function so that the string of the result is built by preprocessor instead of using a `%d` inside `printf`.

I would like actually to program something like
`printf( EXPR_TEST_STRINGIFIED ".......", other args....)` so that the result 4+2 = 6 can be converted into a string directly concatenated inside printf usage.

For now the simplest working code would be **printf("%d .......",EXPR_TEST, other args....);** Here the first %d formatted is used so that printf will print out the (4+2)=6 evaluated expression as integer.

In my case I wonder if I could instead ask preprocessor to directly stringify the result of 4+2 operation but if I use the "regular" stringify macros (`#define xstr(s) str(s)` and `#define str(s) #s`) the printf always print out 4+2 and not 6 when using `xstr(EXPR_TEST)` in parameter ...

Maybe it's not even possible ... please advice !!

Comment: https://ideone.com/1f1Mi4

Comment: Are you trying to stringify the result of `4+2`, `6`, or just the `4+2`? Macro replacement will not replace expressions with evaluations of their results, so there is no normal way to replace `4+2` with `6` and then to stringify `6`. (There are limited abnormal ways to do some arithmetic. They may not apply here.) Do not try to do all preprocessing with the C preprocessor. It is deliberately limited in function. Simply write your own preprocessing software in C or any scripting language and execute that software during the build, then include its output in your program using `#include`.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I cannot go further than the code you posted, so I will just use %d and use part of printf functionality. This is strange because the 4+2 expression was a concept to develop a more complex idea. Actually the expression is a macro to compute DJB2 hash to preprocess text and get hash value then in printf. The macro part is done well by preprocessor but curiously I cannot get a stringification of the result and I have to use %d inside printf ...